# over - partition by in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table TABLE in SQLite database with columns DATE, GROUP. I want to select the first 10 entries in each group. After researching similar topics here on stackoverflow, I came up with the following query, but it runs very slowly. Any ideas how to make it faster?

```
select * from TABLE as A 
where (select count(*) from TABLE as B 
       where B.DATE < A.DATE and A.GROUP == B.GROUP) < 10
```

This is the result of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN (TABLE = clients_bets):

[image: The result of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN]

Comment: Show the table definition and the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this query.

Comment: @CL Not exactly sure what you mean by table definition, but it contains a lot of (~50+) other columns besides the DATE and GROUP, DATE is TEXT and GROUP is INT. I added the output of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN to the question.

Comment: @JosefOndrej do you have any indexes on DATE and GROUP? Why does the database have to perform a SCAN for the inner query? You can't avoid the outer full scan since you *are* asking for the running total for every single row before filtering.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No I did not have any indices on those columns. Now when I added them the query takes 10x less time and in the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output the third row is now "SEARCH TABLE clients_bets AS B USING INDEX ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions :

- Use a covering index (an index containing all the data needed in the subquery, in this case the group and date)

  ```
  create index some_index on some_table(some_group, some_date)
  ```
- Additionally, rewrite the subquery to make is less dependent on outer query :

  ```
  select * from some_table as A
  where rowid in (
      select B.rowid
      from some_table as B 
      where A.some_group == B.some_group 
      order by B.some_date limit 10 )
  ```

  The query plan change from :

  ```
  0   0   0   SCAN TABLE some_table AS A
  0   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED LIST SUBQUERY 1
  1   0   0   SEARCH TABLE some_table AS B USING COVERING INDEX idx_1 (some_group=?)
  ```

  to

  ```
  0   0   0   SCAN TABLE some_table AS A  
  0   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
  1   0   0   SEARCH TABLE some_table AS B USING COVERING INDEX idx_1 (some_group=? AND some_date<?)
  ```

  While it is very similar, the query seems quite faster. I'm not sure why.

Comment: The covering index helped to further reduce the time by a factor of 7, however it does not seem like a good idea to rewrite the query as it is 2x slower than my original proposal.

Comment: Interesting, in my tests it was much faster. Another example of why it's important to profile with real data